# Saving model hides the imageview in tableview

Tags: backbone.js, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am facing a suspicious issue which can't be logically true. On Saving model the some elements in tablerow hides.

Here is the view code `noteRow.xml`

```
<Alloy>
    <TableViewRow id="noteRow">
        <View class="noteRowSeperator"></View>
        <View id="noteRowContainer">
            <View class="noteSideBox">
                <ImageView id="noteStatus" onClick="toggleStatus"></ImageView>
            </View>
            <View class="noteContentBox">
                <Label class="noteDescription" text="{description}"/>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View class="noteRowSeperator"></View>
    </TableViewRow>
</Alloy>
```

Here is the controller code `noteRow.js`

```
var moment = require('alloy/moment');

var  id;
if ($model) {
    id = $model.id;
    if ($model.get('done')) {
        $.noteRowContainer.opacity = 0.5;
        $.noteStatus.image = '/images/status_completed.png';
    } else {
        $.noteRowContainer.opacity = 1;
        $.noteStatus.image = '/images/status_not_completed.png';
    }
}

function toggleStatus(e) {
    alert(id);
    var note = Alloy.Collections.note.get(id);

    note.set({
        "done": note.get('done') ? 0 : 1,
        "completed_at": moment().format('X'),
        "updated_at": moment().format('X')
    }).save();
}
```

When the model saves the all `ImageView` with id `noteStatus` simply hides on all tablerows in tableview. Can't figure out why its having the issue. Please guide me to sort it.

Application type: Mobile 
Titanium SDK: 3.1.2 
Platform: Android (Gynemotion) (Also on my device Galaxy SII) 
Platform Version: 4.1.1

Comment: Have you try adding a button to the table row and in the click event of the button save the model? just to test.

Comment: I tried but its still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. The problem was with `view`.  I updated the view to.

```
<Alloy>
    <TableViewRow id="noteRow">
        <View class="noteRowSeperator"></View>
        <View id="noteRowContainer">
       <ImageView id="noteStatus" onClick="toggleStatus"></ImageView>
            <View class="noteContentBox">
                <Label class="noteDescription" text="{description}"/>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View class="noteRowSeperator"></View>
    </TableViewRow>
</Alloy>
```

Means simply removing `<View class="noteSideBox">` solved the issue. Don't know how but it solved :)